# React-big-calendar - don't know how to store dates in mongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, react-big-calendar

I am trying to display some events coming from my mongo DB in my Calendar by react-big-calendar.

I know that the desired data format is as in their demos:

```
{
    id: 4,
    title: 'Some Event',
    start: new Date(2021, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0),
    end: new Date(2021, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0),
}
```

but I cannot figure out how to store it in my DB. What type of data it is? When I retrieve it from my DB, is that when I declare it with 'new Date()'? Is it supposed to be a string?

I tried storing a date in my DB like this, manually, via postman, just to test it out:

```
start: "2021, 8, 29, 9, 0, 0"
```

and when I retrieve it (with a map over the result of the request) I try to do '(new Date(mydata.start))' but it says 'Invalid Date'

Axios result looks fine, I correctly see the titles, so this is not the issue.

I only need an example of data that can be sent to mongoDB as well as retrieved and displayed in the calendar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the parameters to the Date constructor as a string, if `start` is a Date on Mongo, it will lead to a cast error if you try validating it, as that string cannot be passed into `new Date()`.

If `start` is a string, use the following:

```
new Date(...mydata.start.split(", "))
```

To pass the parameters back, that is called the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Or alternatively store a string that can easily be turned into a date, by using  `(new Date(2021, 8, 29, 9, 0, 0)).toDateString()` for example, or a similar method, then you can simply `new Date(mydata.start)`

It also would be a great idea to directly store as a Date object:

```
start: new Date(2021, 8, 29, 9, 0, 0)
```